# Console.getLine and Console.getString not taking in all of user input - JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to take in user input (the name of a country) to add to a list of countries that I display. However, it is not letting me enter the name of a country longer than 8 characters. 
For example, when I input "Venezuela" the output is "Venezuel" and when I input "United States" the output is "United S" 
Below is the method I used to accept the user input. I have tried Console.getString as well as Console.getLine and neither are working to accept more than 8 characters.

```
 public static void addCountry() {
    String name = Console.getString("Enter country name: ");

    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName(name);
    countryDAO.add(country);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(name
            + " has been added.\n");
}
```

I also have these methods in the Console class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console {

private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String getLine(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    String s = sc.nextLine();        
    return s;
}

public static String getString(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    String s = sc.next();        
    sc.nextLine();               
    return s;
}
}
```

Comment: `java.io.Console` does not have a `getString()` method. Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: @GBlodgett I have a getString() method in my console class

Comment: The fun thing is, there is a Java class named `Console`, so there is potential for confusion.

Comment: I cannot reproduce

Comment: getLine() which users nextLine() can accept more than 8 chars. Check if the 8 chars requirement exists in your counrtryDAO or in the database(if exists)

Answer (score -1):

Use this to take input instead of sc.next():

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

and remove the next line where you have added sc.nextLine()

Hope that helps!